# Is it possible to get the current request that is being served by node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using express.js. I have a need to be able to log certain request data whenever someone tries to log a message. For this I would like to create a helper method like so

```
function log_message(level, message){
  winston.log(level, req.path + "" + message);
}
```

I would then use the method like so.

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  log_message("info", "I'm here");
}
```

Note that I am not passing the req object to the log_message function. I want that to be transparently done so that the log_message API user does not need to be aware of the common data that is being logged.

Is there a way to achieve this with express.js/node.js. Is the request object available from a global variable of some sort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution is acceptable to me.

In here I have a middleware which adds the log_message method onto the request object. After that I simply call req.log_message to log the message. While this is very similar to passing the req object to every logging call it's just slightly cleaner.

```
function logging_middleware(req, res, next){
    req.log_message = function(level, message){
        winston.log(level, req.path + ":" + message);
    }
    next();
}
```

Answer (score 10):

An interesting way to do this would be the new Domains feature.
http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html

Domains, while providing excellent error recovery, can be used as a type of "Thread Local Storage" - basically storing data for each request.

Create some middleware that adds every request/response to a domain.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var reqd = domain.create();
  reqd.add(req);
  reqd.add(res);
  reqd._req = req; // Add request object to custom property
  // TODO: hook error event on reqd (see docs)
  next();
});
```

In the log function, you can now get the current domain and pull out the request object.

```
function log_message(level, message) {
  // Pull the request from the current domain.
  var request = process.domain._req;

  // TODO: log message
};
```

Domains are still experimental, but it doesn't sound like much will change between now and the 1.0 release.

Comment: Creating a domain does not automatically set process.domain to that domain. So in log_message process.domain is actually undefined.

Comment: @MoizRaja So how does one actually add the domain to the process that it's available later on?

Comment: @ChristopherWill: `process.domain = reqd;` in the middleware worked for me. Sadly couldn't find documentation to describe the behavior :-/

Comment: Instead of calling `next()`, call `reqd.run(next)`.

"The `enter` method is plumbing used by the `run`, `bind`, and `intercept` methods to set the active domain. It sets `domain.active` and `process.domain` to the domain" http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html#domain_domain_enter

Comment: Don't use it anymore: "This module is pending deprecation"

Answer (score 6):

Similar to the domains answer, it's now a lot easier to do this using continuation-local-storage: https://datahero.com/blog/2014/05/22/node-js-preserving-data-across-async-callbacks/

At DataHero we save a transaction id, user id, and session id with all log messages. You don't need to pass the request object all the way down, so it helps keep your models / business layer clean, too.

Comment: Be aware of the issues you'll run into when using CLS: https://github.com/othiym23/node-continuation-local-storage/issues/59

Answer (score 5):

create a midleware:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
       var tid = uuid.v4();
     var cls = require('continuation-local-storage');
       var namespace = cls.createNamespace('com.storage');
      var pre_ip;
          if(get_ip(req))
          { ip_info= get_ip(req).clientIp;
              pre_ip=ip_info
          }
          namespace.bindEmitter(req);
          namespace.bindEmitter(res);
        namespace.run(function() {
               console.log(logobj);
              namespace.set('tid', tid);
              namespace.set('ip',ip_info);
           namespace.set('logobj',logobj);   
              next();
          });
      });
```

And use it :

```
var cls = require('continuation-local-storage');
 var namespace = cls.getNamespace('com.storage');
      namespace.get('ip');
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working with async/await flow. you can easy try to "wait" 3 seconds on controller and then output data. And send fast two requests to your app - only second will show correct data, first will be undefined, so it will not work with async way. But will work in case of direct request chain call without "thread" race condition.

Comment: Just an update : found thread-safe solution, check please my answer in thread.

Answer (score 3):

How is the `log_message` exposed to the caller (a module, etc) and what control do you have over the pipeline preceding the route?

You could apply middleware preceding this route's invocation and have the function `log_message` come from within a closure, or you could take advantage of the `req` EventEmitter facility and wrap the call to winston.log inside a handler for the req.end and just log all messages that have been made during the request. This would effectively change your `log_message` to be an accumulator of log messages (maybe in an Array) and just log them all at the end of the request.

This all depends on how you are exposing this stuff though.

Many cats have been skinned here :)

Answer (score 1):

I **found working "thread safe" solution** to pass data across whole request without modifying req object and pass it through all layers.

So, we have [continuation-local-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/continuation-local-storage) package, that allow us to bind req at the start of req and then reuse on next calls. But it feels bad when you are trying to use chain of async calls, CLS is not "thread-safe" and if you will try to call it during few concurrent requests - it will fail and lost "context".

So, we have [cls-hooked](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cls-hooked) package, that fixing this issue and we can easy catch current context binding request on the request start.

There are a small example of using awilix (Dependency injection framework) and we will create "RequestContext" class and **be able to use it everywhere we need**.

Let's create RequestContext class :

```
module.exports = class RequestContext {

 constructor(req, res, dependencies) {
 const { myService1, myService2 } = dependencies;    
 this.req = req;
 this.res = res;
}

getMyTestHeader() {
 return this.req.headers.testHeader;
}
```

It is a simple "request wrapper". It consume request,response and other dependencies if you need and provide getMyTestHeader to use out of class.

Let's create middleware at the request start (before all others) :

```
  //Registering our namespace. creating it one per app
  const clsNamespace = require('cls-hooked').createNamespace('my-per-request-session'); 
  app.use((req, res, next) => {
      // binding continuation-local-storage (cls-hooked) to request and response
      clsNamespace.bind(req);
      clsNamespace.bind(res);
      clsNamespace.run(() => {
      // save here req and res to use it later in requestContext instance, it will alive during request and could be picked up from DI as other dependencies
       clsNamespace.set('req', req);
       clsNamespace.set('res', res);
       next();
      });

  });
```

Now, let's register DI call using awilix :

```
container.register({  
requestContextProvider: asFunction(dependencies => ({
 getCurrentContext: () => {
  //retrieve res and req on each DI call "from current request"
  //also, clsNamespace should be the same as we registered before, on original code it is also registered using DI container.
  const req = dependencies.clsNamespace.get('req');
  const res = dependencies.clsNamespace.get('res');
  //and return our RequestContext (wrapper for req and res)
  return new RequestContext(req, res, dependencies);
 },
})),
```

So, we are registering requestContextProvider as function, that will be instantiated with req and res from outer context (cls) on each request on each DI dependencie call.
As a result we can use it next way (in controller, for example) :

```
module.exports = (dependencies) => ({
 myControllerAction: async (req, res) => {
  const {requestContextProvider} = dependencies;
  const requestContext = requestContextProvider.getCurrentContext();
  //it will return header from req!
  const myHeader = requestContext.getMyTestHeader(); 
  res.status(200).json({ myHeader });
 },    
});
```

as you can see, we now have "requestContext" everywhere we can access DI on every layer level (controllers/BLL/DAL/helpers and etc). So, it is "thread-safe", easy to test and not require to throw down req object through all "middle" layers.

Agree, not the best and easy examle, but hope, it helps someone.